# Client certificates after CA renewal

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl, ca

I have a root CA that was used to generate both server and client certificates in a currently working system.

It will soon reach its expiration date, and I am trying to renew it without changing any server or client certificate but I have failed so far.

To renew the CA, I have used:

```
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out newcsr.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in newcsr.csr -signkey ca.key -out newca.pem
```

Then I have replaced my old CA certificate by newca.pem.
I expected that to be enough to have it working, but unfortunately it does not.

When trying to send a request with CuRL using my old client certificates (which are not expired), I get this error message:

```
curl --cert clientcrt.pem --key clientkey.pem https://myserver/
```

> (35) Peer does not recognize and trust the CA that issued your
>   certificate

(the same request with the old CA does work, since it is not yet expired)

What are the steps that I missed?
Or do you have any clue of causes of error that I may look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be useful to anyone, I finally resolved this problem by setting the serial of my new CA to the same value than the serial of the old CA:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -set_serial <oldserial> -out newca.pem
```

With that my client certificates are successfully validated by my CA.